# Upload video to azure blob storage through azure media services .NET SDK

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

So far all the samples on azure regarding azure media services, expect that files in general must be stored locally in order to upload to azure media services.

The reason being is that the `CreateFromFile()` has two parameters: string filePath and options.

Example:

```
static public IAsset UploadFile(string fileName, AssetCreationOptions options)
{
    IAsset inputAsset = _context.Assets.CreateFromFile(
        fileName,
        options,
        (af, p) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading '{0}' - Progress: {1:0.##}%", af.Name, p.Progress);
        });

    Console.WriteLine("Asset {0} created.", inputAsset.Id);

    return inputAsset;
}
```

Now what if the video has been passed in the body of a post API?
How would one try to approach such a challenge?

Answer (score 0):

> So far all the samples on azure regarding azure media services, expect that files in general must be stored locally in order to upload to azure media services.

It also supports to create IAsset  from the blob `CreateFromBlob`, but it seems that creating IAsset  from stream is not supported now. I also find an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/issues/45) about this.

> Now what if the video has been passed in the body of a post API? How would one try to approach such a challenge?

In your case if I understand correctly, you could save the files in you API server **template folder/another Azure blob storage** then **delete** it template files/blobs after finish the action.

Comment: Yeah that's one way of doing it.

For now what I did, is to upload to my blob storage through the sdk of blob storage, instead of using media services.

I was able to upload through the stream.

Thanks for your reply. I will update this question, if ever I transfer my blobs to media services.